# Como reemplazo un dato ingresado por otro en Python?

Tags: python, excel, formularios

Tengo una base con información almacenada en Excel, para lo que Visual conecta con el xlsx mandando el contenido a una web tipo formulario, me arroja todos los datos pero de forma consecutiva y quisiera que al ingresar la información al pasar 5 segundos borre la anterior y ponga la nueva.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo he hecho con ciclo for ya que es una cantidad de datos grande mayor a las 50 que puse en rango solo quiero que me reemplace la información, hasta ahora no encuentro como hacerlo o si hay otro código similar para una cantidad de datos enorme. Gracias

Comment: Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. El código siempre _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden leer las imágenes. Además, elimina el editor (VSCode) de la pregunta, ya que nada tiene que ver con la misma. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. No olvides además mostrar el resultado esperado y el obtenido.

Comment: Opción 1: Si lo impreso mide una sola linea, al print el argumento end="\r", que envía el cursor al principio de la linea y con otro print, sobreescribe lo anterior usando espacios extra al final, creando una cadena que mida como la anterior. Opcion 2: Usa el comando cls o clear (según el sistema operativo) y vuelve a escribir en pantalla todo lo que no querías borrar. Opción 3: usa un módulo externo. Un muy bueno es [blessed](https://pypi.org/project/blessed/)

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por sus consejos, al final me sirvió el clear() ya que estoy usando una base de datos en excel y al ingresar un dato ejecuta clear y pasa al siguiente dato.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.